# asp.net mvc 5 website hangs nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce

My aim is to define a problem here! I couldn't define my problem so I couldn't solve it yet.. So I need suggestions to understand the case.

First of all my problem is about Nopcommerce. I want to tell the story first. Then I will wait your suggestions.

I'm using nopcommerce 3.50. I developed one payment, one shipping and one miscellaneous plugin which includes some special things for our business. Anyway I did not touch the core of nopcommerce.

As for the server environment; Windows Server 2012, IIS 8 and Sql Server 2012.

Ok then, what was happened. We just announced and opened yesterday; last night approximately 2000 people visited the web site.. After that when traffic start to decrease web site stopped to response (hangs). After I saving web.config file application restarted and things turned to normal, since today morning. After this morning every hour maybe less than one hour, application stopped to respond even there were no such traffic on it and even CPU and memory status were so normal..

When I looked at the nopcommerce logs, there is no significant thing to understand the case, also there is no any evidence in windows event logs..

What can cause such problem, my brain really stuck.. I couldn't think healthily.. Please provide me some suggestions..

Comment: What type of server you are using? VPS or Physical Server? Whats the amount of RAM it has? Are you using same server for SQL Server and IIS?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own logger and attach it to the on error event. And possibly attach a remote debugger

Comment: You should add it as comment - I don't think it's actually answer for @AOZ problem :)

Comment: He's asking for advice. And the only thing to do is that. :)

Comment: Actually you are right @Hellraiser i start to use a custom logger.. And now I understand the problems.. But unfortunately those type of errors are headaches. nothing else :) thank you..

Answer (score 1):

I have faced almost same issue. We were using same VPS for SQL Server and Nop Commerce. VPS had about 2GB. After long struggle, with help of pleask monitor, i managed to isolate the issue towards memory. When system ramps up with more users, Nop Commerce loads more data in-to memory cache. On other side, SQL Server tend to eat up more than 1GB. So system started to crash.

As a solution, i have purchased one more GB ram and set SQL Server to consume maximum of only 1GB. Then system started to run normally. Best configuration is to give atleast 1GB for SQL Server and 1GB for Nop Commerce.